# Attach to Windows Guest a Pool Storage Directory KVM

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I just created a storage pool directory based in my Host KVM

```
# virsh pool-list --all

Name                 State      Autostart 
-----------------------------------------
guest_images_dir     active     yes
```

And the info:

```
# virsh pool-info guest_images_dir

Name:           guest_images_dir
UUID:           720c6735-9ca0-e7c2-18cf-396c729a512e
State:          running
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Capacity:       920.54 GB
Allocation:     23.02 GB
Available:      897.51 GB
```

Here is the XML

```
# cat /etc/libvirt/storage/autostart/guest_images_dir.xml 

<pool type='dir'>
  <name>guest_images_dir</name>
  <uuid>720c6735-9ca0-e7c2-18cf-396c729a512e</uuid>
  <capacity>0</capacity>
  <allocation>0</allocation>
  <available>0</available>
  <source>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/home/virtuals/shared_dir_kvm</path>
    <permissions>
          <mode>0700</mode>
          <owner>-1</owner>
          <group>-1</group>
        </permissions>
  </target>
</pool>
```

But I can't see it on my guest Windows 2008. What else do I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pool is a place where you are supposed to place images. You will not see it form the VM, because what the VM can see are images, as disks, not the grouping of the images in pools.

If you go into the pool, and create a volume there, and attach that volume to the VM, it will see a new attached disk, it will be able to format and use

Comment: So I can't share a host folder to multiples guest at the same time? Without using NFS, SMB, etc I mean. Because if I use SMB or NFS I only have speeds around ~10MB/s (ethernet speed) and I want to get the HDD's speed

Comment: you can, but you set up a shared volume for that. And if a lot of systems will be using it, you need a clustered FS

Comment: Is there any website that explain that? I have been looking for it but I can't found anything to share a volume or "mount point" for HOST and multiples GUESTs at the same time

Comment: no, you can only share a virtual disk image between guests. That disk image is a volume in the libvirt storage pool. If you need to access this image from the host you have libguestfs/guestfish for that

Comment: Is it sure and recommended?

Comment: Either this or you need to export NFS/SMB from the host, and connect to it from the guest

Comment: But with NFS/SMB I will have always the limitation of 10MB/s, because my ethernet. Right?

Comment: Where did you see such a limitation? The stack is not in fact limited in speed internally, just make sure you use virtio_net. But really, this question has already been answered, if you have more, open a new one

Comment: I have a bridge for my VM's and if I try to copy something between NFS (host) and wherever directory of my VM, the speed average is around 8~10MB/s